# C# - Azure Blob SAS Key not Well Formed

Tags: c#, azure

I'm working on setting up a script that can generate SAS keys for different users in our organization to access different files. I'm using the Azure SDK to take the blob and generate the key based on a found blob client. After setting up the BlobSasBuilder and generating the Uri and going to it, I get a signature not well formed auth error. I've verified that the blob is valid and can be access with an auth'd account through the portal but I can't figure out what else I can do.

Here is my current test code for the SAS:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StorageSharedKeyCredential keyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
    BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{accountName}.file.core.usgovcloudapi.net"), keyCredential);

    BlobClient blobClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("account-data").GetBlobClient("ADImport.csv");
    Uri sasURL = CreateServiceASBlob(blobClient);

    Console.WriteLine(sasURL);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static Uri CreateServiceASBlob(BlobClient blobClient)
{
    if (blobClient.CanGenerateSasUri)
    {
        BlobSasBuilder sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
        {
            BlobContainerName = blobClient.GetParentBlobContainerClient().Name,
            BlobName = blobClient.Name,
            Resource = "b",
            StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(-1),
            ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1)
        };
        
        sasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobAccountSasPermissions.Read);

        return blobClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);
    }

    return null;
}
```

So far I have tried to generate the query parameters and append to the url but with no success. I'm expecting the download event to happen upload accessing the link but have been unsuccessful in doing so. The code provided along with my google searches have yielded no success and I would appreciate any additional help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your target file is file of Azure Files because your storage account is `*.file.core.usgovcloudapi.net`.

If you want to generate SAS for Azure Files (not blob), please you should use `Azure.Storage.Files.Shares`.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files

sample code

```cs
        var fsc = new Azure.Storage.Files.Shares.ShareClient("<your storage connection string", "<your share name>");
        var fd = fsc.GetDirectoryClient("<directory path>");
        var f = fd.GetFileClient("<file name>");

        var fileSasBuilder = new ShareSasBuilder(ShareFileSasPermissions.Read,
            DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1))
            {
                ShareName = "<share name>",
                FilePath = "<directory and file path>"
            };
        
        var fileUrlWithSAS = f.GenerateSasUri(fileSasBuilder);
```

Comment: I realized the actual issue. I had the wrong URL from when I was testing something with file shares since we couldn't get a file share to persist on a device using powershell.